# Adding the function parameters to an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, push, new-operator

I've got a function along with an instance made using "new" :

```
function Cars (model, color, year) {
this.model = model;
this.color = color;
this.year = year;
this.allCars = [];

}

var bmw = new Cars('z4', 'white', 2010),
    benz = new Cars('cl', 'black', 2011),
    ford = new Cars('mustang', 'red', 2015),
    audi = new Cars('s3', 'yellow', 2013),
    fiat= new Cars('fat boy', 'purple', 2020);


Cars.prototype.addCars = function (data) {
for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
   this.allCars.push(data);
  return this.allCars;  
}
}

console.log(benz.addCars(bmw,audi,fiat));
console.log(benz.addCars(ford));
```

I've tried to create a function named "addCars" such that whenever I assign an instance to it ,like benz.addCars(x1,x2,x3,...),I'd be able to get an array of the cars mentioned as the parameters.

for example, I would expect to get the following result when I call

```
console.log(benz.addCars(bmw,audi,fiat))
// expected result: ['bmw','audi',fiat']
```

and the following result for a single parameter instance:

```
console.log(benz.addCars(ford));
//expected result: ['ford']
```

I'm just wondering how I can get this array filled using the function addCard.
cheers

Comment: Don't forget about indentation. It's important to make your code more readable: Communicate structure and intent.

Comment: `push(data[I])` but change the loop to use `data.length`.  Use `Array.isArray` for the other case (or use `...data` for argument.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about ..data? I know that when there's supposed to return the parameters of a function ,there's something to do with "..data" ,but I don't know what key words to search for. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider using a class setup like this:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(brand, model, color, year) {
    this._brand = brand
    this._model = model
    this._color = color
    this._year = year
  }
  get brand() {
    return this._brand
  }
}

class Cars {
  constructor(cars = []) {
    this._cars = cars
  }
  addCars(cars) {
    cars.forEach(c => this._cars.push(c))
  }
  getBrands() {
    return this._cars.map(x => x.brand)
  }
}

let cars = new Cars([
  new Car('BMW', 'z4', 'white', 2010),
  new Car('Mercedes', 'cl', 'black', 2011),
  new Car('Ford', 'mustang', 'red', 2015),
  new Car('Audi', 's3', 'yellow', 2013),
  new Car('Fiat', 'fat boy', 'purple', 2020)
])

console.log(cars.getBrands())
```

Where you could use ES6 getter/setters etc.

Here is another way to do this with your setup:

```js
function Cars(brand, model, color, year) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.model = model;
  this.color = color;
  this.year = year;
  this.allCars = [];

}

var bmw = new Cars('BMW', 'z4', 'white', 2010),
  benz = new Cars('Mercedes', 'cl', 'black', 2011),
  ford = new Cars('Ford', 'mustang', 'red', 2015),
  audi = new Cars('Audi', 's3', 'yellow', 2013),
  fiat = new Cars('Fiat', 'fat boy', 'purple', 2020);


Cars.prototype.addCars = function(data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.allCars.push(data[i]);
    }
    return data.map(x => x.brand)
  } else {
    this.allCars.push(data);
    return data.brand
  }
}

console.log(benz.addCars([bmw, audi, fiat]));
console.log(benz.addCars([ford]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code,but the fact of the matter is ,there's no need to accumulate all the brands in one array,it's more like giving a brand and get its fellow competitors according to the number of parameters. I would like to make the result dependent on the parameters passed. something like the following :

console.log(audi.addCars(ford));
//expected result: ['ford']

or

console.log(audi.addCars(bmw,ford,fiat))
// expected result: ['bmw','ford',fiat']

Comment: awesome!  runs like a well-oiled machine!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below method/ answer.

```
function Cars (model, color, year) {
this.model = model;
this.color = color;
this.year = year;
this.allCars = [];

}

var bmw = new Cars('z4', 'white', 2010),
   benz = new Cars('cl', 'black', 2011),
   ford = new Cars('mustang', 'red', 2015),
   audi = new Cars('s3', 'yellow', 2013),
   fiat= new Cars('fat boy', 'purple', 2020);


Cars.prototype.addCars = function (data) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     this.allCars.push(arguments[i]);
   }
  return this.allCars;  
}

 console.log(benz.addCars(bmw,audi,fiat));
 console.log(benz.addCars(ford));
```

Comment: this returns the following:
(3) [Cars, Cars, Cars]
and
(4)[Cars,Cars,Cars,Cars]